# User making VERY bad edits

Tags: discussion, status-completed, editing, new-users

Today I saw a red dot in suggested edits and then there were 6 edits by [this user](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/50857/blah) which literally just had the whole text deleted and the word spam replaced instead. I rejected these edits, but this user has now copied and pasted 4 low quality answers that were exactly the same as well. Can something be done about it?

Comment: I will just like to say that the user has now recreated another user. The story hasn't ended yet. Here is the new user https://space.stackexchange.com/users/50863/spammer. He says on his profile that we will create a new user each time you delete his old user. Is it possible to ban the IP-Address from where these users are coming from?

Comment: Posted a question about it @The Rocket fan

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch, I wonder if something can be done

Comment: If not then there should be @The Rocket fan

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch true

Comment: Total spam count:
Edits:12
Answers:6
Questions:3
thats a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user was already automatically blocked by the system, but I went ahead and destroyed their account as well, since it was clearly not intended to be used in good faith.

Comment: Okay. Good to know

Comment: By the way, there is a new sockpuppet @called2voyage

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Please flag one of the posts that the sock made or edited, as I have no way of checking the information on an account after I destroy it.

Comment: New sockpuppet just destroy as well, I will flag one anyways that way we can prevent a third @called2voyage